# Why is copy constructor not being called in this code

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So why is Copy constructor not being invoked in "**const Integer operator+(const Integer &rv)**" function. Is it because of RVO. **If Yes what do I need to do to prevent it?**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Integer {
    int i;

public:
    Integer(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {
        cout << "Integer()" << endl;
    }

    Integer(const Integer &I) {
        cout << "Integer(const Integer &)" << endl;
    }

    ~Integer() {
        cout << "~Integer()" << endl;
    }

    const Integer operator+(const Integer &rv) const {
        cout << "operator+" << endl;
        Integer I(i + rv.i);
        I.print();
        return I;
    }

    Integer &operator+=(const Integer &rv) {
        cout << "operator+=" << endl;
        i + rv.i;
        return *this;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "i: " << i << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "built-in tpes:" << endl;
    int i = 1, j = 2, k = 3;
    k += i + j;
    cout << "user-defined types:" << endl;
    Integer ii(1), jj(2), kk(3);
    kk += ii + jj;

}
```

I do get an error If I'll comment out copy constructor. I'm expecting copy constructor to be called when operator+ returns. Following is the output of the program

```
built-in tpes:
user-defined types:
Integer()
Integer()
Integer()
operator+
Integer()
i: 3 // EXPECTING Copy Constructor to be called after this
operator+=
~Integer()
~Integer()
~Integer()
~Integer()
```

Comment: Where did you expect your copy constructor to be called?

Comment: Showing what is printed out would give us some more insight into the actual situation you're facing. And by the way, your copy constructor doesn't copy anything. Or is the copy constructor of `I::i` invoked automatically? I don't think so, but am not completely sure.

Comment: @AndréPuel: He is expecting copy-ctor to be called when `operator+` returns!

Comment: And your `operator +=` is wrong, the middle line probably should say `i += rv.i;`

Comment: If you need to disable RVO, then chances are you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Why would you want to disable RVO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it because of RVO. If Yes what do I need to do to prevent it?

Yes. But it didn't get called because of [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) by the compiler.

If you're using GCC, then use `-fno-elide-constructors` option to avoid it.

[GCC 4.6.1 manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options) says,

> **-fno-elide-constructors**
>
> The C++ standard allows an implementation to omit creating a temporary which is only used to initialize another object of the same type. Specifying this option disables that optimization, and forces G++ to call the copy constructor in all cases.

Comment: It worked. But is there any other way to do this with compiler options. I called print on the local object inside operator+ thinking it will prevent RVO.

Comment: @NikhilRathod: What do you mean by that? What worked? All I'm saying is about compiler options, what else are you talking about?

Comment: @NikhilRathod: Yes. Now what is your next question? You seem to have one?

Comment: What do I need to do with local object I in operator+ so that the compiler will not do RVO?

Comment: @NikhilRathod: If you don't want to use any compiler option to prevent RVO, and instead you want to do something with the local object so as to avoid RVO, then to the best of my knowledge, you cannot do anything with local object, to prevent RVO.

Comment: @NikhilRathod: You should avoid side-effects (e.g. print something, register 'self' somewhere etc.) in copy constructors at all. Even avoid them in regular constructors. This will lead to a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

(N)RVO is one of the easiest to implement optimizations. In most calling conventions for return by value the caller reserves the space for the returned object and then passes a hidden pointer to the function. The function then *constructs* the object in the address that is given. That is, `kk += ii + jj;` is translated into something like:

```
Integer __tmp;

//                  __rtn  this  arg
Integer::operator+( &tmp,  &ii,  jj );

kk += __tmp;
```

The function (in this case `Integer::operator+` takes a first hidden argument `__rtn` that is a pointer to an uninitialized block of memory of `sizeof(Integer)` bytes, where the object is to be constructed, a second hidden argument `this`, and then the argument to the function in the code.

Then the implementation of the function is translated into:

```
Integer::operator+( Integer* __rtn, Integer const * this, const Integer &rv) {
    cout << "operator+" << endl;
    new (__rtn) Integer(i + rv.i);
    __rtn->print();
}
```

Because the calling convention passes the pointer, there function does not need to reserve extra space for a local integer that would then be copied, as it can just build the `I` in your code straight into the received pointer, and avoid the copy.

Note that not in all circumstances the compiler can perform NRVO, in particular, if you have two local objects in the function and you return either one depending on a condition that is not inferable from the code (say the value of an argument to the function). While you could do that to avoid RVO, the fact is that it will make your code more complex, less efficient and harder to maintain.