# Does Type t = Type() call the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization, copy-constructor

I'm really confused.... does `Type t = Type()` call the copy constructor or no?

I'm asking because when I try:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(Test const &) { std::cout << "hello"; }
    Test() { }
};

int main()
{
    Test t = Test();
    return 0;
}
```

nothing is output, but when I change it to

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    Test(Test const &) { std::cout << "hello"; }
public:
    Test() { }
};

int main()
{
    Test t = Test();
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
error C2248: 'Test::Test' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Test'
```

which doesn't make sense (especially since this is a debug build).

#### Update:

Even this compiles!

```
struct Test
{
    Test(Test &&) = delete;
    Test(Test const &) = delete;
    Test() { }
};

int main()
{
    Test t = Test();
    return 0;
}
```

So is a copy/move constructor necessary or no?

Comment: Side effects are allowed to be ignored in copy elision. It still needs to be accessible, though.

Comment: @chris: Are you sure copy elision is happening here? This is a debug build...

Comment: You would think the move constructor would be a possibility, but seeing as how it's failing when it can't call the copy constructor, it's either only using that or there's a rule I'm forgetting.

Comment: @chris: I totally forgot about the move constructor. I think the copy ctor is suppressing it, because the same exact thing happens when I replace `Test const &` with `Test &&`. Same mystery as before: does it require a move constructor?

Comment: If they are both there as public, Both those constructors will be called for that one initialization.

Comment: According to @chris, I think this post explains similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890528/copy-constructor-elision

Comment: And here is the way to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779827/why-is-copy-constructor-not-being-called-in-this-code?rq=1, i.e. `-fno-elide-constructors`

Comment: I find it really interesting that deleting something in addition to the copy constructor makes it work.

Comment: @Mehrdad This DOSE NOT COMPILE. `g++ 4.8`

Comment: @gongzhitaao: Sorry just realized I said `class` instead of `struct` on the last one...

Comment: @Mehrdad still not compile.

Comment: @gongzhitaao: Ooh... is it a compiler bug then?

Comment: tested with `g++ tmp.cpp -std=c++11` with `g++ 4.8` on ubuntu.  And please see my previous reference and try `-fno-elide-constructors` with your original question.

Comment: @gongzhitaao: Er I know you tested with g++. I mean is it a Visual C++ bug then?

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't know then:P I just test.  But it seems that chris is right about the elision.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I suspected it was a compiler bug when writing my last comment. In fact, it does not compile on the MSVC12 CTP, while it does on the normal MSVC12.

Comment: @chris: Interesting, it's a bug then, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From wikipedia:

> In C++ computer programming, copy elision refers to a compiler
>   optimization technique that eliminates unnecessary copying of objects.
>   The C++ language standard generally allows implementations to perform
>   any optimization, provided the resulting program's observable behavior
>   is the same as if, i.e. pretending, the program was executed exactly
>   as mandated by the standard.
>
> The standard also describes a few situations where copying can be
>   eliminated even if this would alter the program's behavior, the most
>   common being the return value optimization. Another widely implemented
>   optimization, described in the C++ standard, is when a temporary
>   object of class type is copied to an object of the same type.[1] **As
>   a result, copy-initialization is usually equivalent to
>   direct-initialization in terms of performance, but not in semantics;
>   copy-initialization still requires an accessible copy
>   constructor**.[2] The optimization can not be applied to a temporary
>   object that has been bound to a reference.

You are doing a copy construction, but the standard allows it to be converted to a direct initialization, and that is being done regardless of debug turned off, that's why the print isnt reached..

But, because it "should" be a copy construction, you do need access to one, which is why the second code doesnt work.

Comment: Tough question: why does this work, then? `struct Test { Test(Test const &&) = delete; Test(Test &&) = delete; Test() { } };` `int main() { Test t = Test(); return 0; }`

Comment: that give me compile errors:  error: use of deleted function 'Test::Test(Test&&)'